# how to call a spring mvc controller method from a java class which listens to exceptions?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring web application from which i call other non-spring application(mule application). From Spring MVC controller method i am calling mule flows. I have a listener class in spring application which listens to the exceptions thrown by mule. On excpetion i have to stop the current controller method execution and a message should be displayed to the user with details about the execption. How to achieve this? can we stop mvc controller method execution from listener class and redirect to an error page?

The flow of execution is as follows:

**without exceptions**

MVC controller method1()---> mule------>(on successful execution) continues method1() execution -->xslt view resolver --> displays result in browser

**with exceptions**

MVC controller method1()---> mule------>(on exception will get notification to listener) listener class --->continues method1() execution---> which processes wrong data, shows mule exception

**Desired flow in case of exceptions**

MVC controller method1---> mule------>(on exception will get notification to listener) listener class ---> stop method1 of MVC controller--> redirect to method2 of MVC controller--->display details about exception message in browser

Please suggest a solution for this

Comment: Is it possible to call a controller method from another java class in spring MVC?

Comment: Why not use standard Spring's exception handling (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers)?

Comment: @PavelHoral I have integrated Mule with Spring. Calling a mule flow from spring controller. If something goes wrong in mule code it throws exception but it will not stop spring code execution. I can't catch the exception directly in spring. So i have created a listener to get notified when mule throws exception.